# Secure and Filter certain data "Keys" inside the FireStore document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation, geofirestore

I am developing an application that needs to search all nearby users WITHOUT sharing their coordinates within 100 miles let's say. The example below I am using GeoHash to help me in calculating the distance.

In FireStore, I have the following document inside collection of users.

```
{
   "userId" : "12345",
   "displayName" : "username",
   "geoHash" : "gbsuv",
   "photoUrl" : "example.com/user.jpg",
   "refId" : "0001"
}
```

The question is: How should I protect the "geoHash" from being retrieved within each document inside the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore security rules grant access on a document level. So either the user can read an entire document, or they can't read anything in that document. There's no way to grant users access to only part of a document.

This means that you can't query something that the client can't read. So in your current structure, if the user needs to query on `geoHash`, they will be able to read that field too.

The only alternative is to not let the client do the querying, but instead do that querying on a server (such as in Cloud Functions). For this you'd store the geohash for each user in a separate document (say in a collection called `locations`). The Cloud Function then queries this collection, and returns the real user document(s) (which doesn't contain the geohash anymore) to the user.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, if this is the case I would have the Cloud Functions sanitizing the data by removing the geoHash keys before return the data back to the app. Is this going to work! right?.

Comment: That's also an option, although I'd more likely do what I said in the answer: create a collection with the geo-data, and have the server query that and return the IDs to the client. Remove the geohash from the user documents. Now the client can read the user documents as you're doing already. Either approach is fine though, so pick whatever seems best to you.

Comment: Great! Thank you for help.